# svnadmin dump of text only, without binary files

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndump

It is possible to filter the SVN dump, generated by `svndamin dump`, so it will not included encoded binary data, just the text deltas and data?

I want to have a dump of an existing large SVN repositories, but only of the code. I have no interest in the stored binaries. However, binary files will make the dump file unnecessarily large. How can I generate the dump and exclude binary content?

Tried and failed, already:

1. It is not practical to process the `svn log` diffs. It is a large and old repository, and getting diffs only for a short time period takes a lot of time and often gets stuck.
2. The binary files are scattered all over, and not stored under a single known path, so I cannot use `svndumpfilter` to exclude them - Unless there is some way to use this filter with regular expressions, e.g. `*.jar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html) is part of any Subversion installation

> `svndumpfilter exclude` — Filter out nodes with given prefixes from the dump stream.

Beginning in Subversion 1.7, svndumpfilter can optionally treat the PATH_PREFIXs not merely as explicit substrings, but as file patterns instead.

```
$ svndumpfilter exclude --pattern "*.OLD" < dumpfile > filtered-dumpfile
Excluding prefix patterns:
   '/*.OLD'
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if svndumpfilter accepts "or-patterns", such as "`*.jar|*.pdf`"?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - no, only single pattern. But you can use more than one `exclude` in single command

Comment: To exclude multiple file types, specify `svndumpfilter exclude --pattern --targets list.txt`, where `list.txt` is a text file containing one file type specification per line, as described at [HOWTO purge undesired files from your SVN repository](https://www.stefanobordoni.cloud/howto-purge-undesired-files-from-your-svn-repository/).  You also need to specify the input and output files, and perhaps the options `--drop-empty-revs --skip-missing-merge-sources`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a stock tool to do this.  But it shouldn't be hard to do if you start with this perl module: [SVN::Dumpfilter](https://metacpan.org/pod/SVN%3a%3aDumpfilter)

One of the example scripts in there (svndump_delpathfilter) is probably pretty close to what you want.  My experience with this module is that you'll probably have to tinker with it a bit to get it to do what you want.

Now, I don't think there is any way to reliably tell a binary from a text file, since Subversion (at the lowest levels) doesn't really care.  A quick scan of my repository shows that the svn:mime-type property isn't always set, and I see no other indicative fields.  So you'll have to check via name or (somehow) try looking at the contents of the file (but I have never done the latter).